# How to edit rtl pdf in LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, pdf, rtl

I have to fill a pdf form in Hebrew. The original file seems to be  created in Windows.
I open the pdf in LibreOffice (Version: 5.1.6.2) and it reverses order of letters.
The language of the document is set to Hebrew, it does not help.
Moreover, if I guess what was the field to fill in and write something there, exporting to pdf back keeps the letters reversed!

Is this a bug in LibreOffice?

I tried to install Master PDF Editor. It opens the file correctly. However, when I try to write in Hebrew, it says the current font does not have these symbols and non-commercial version does not allow changing fonts.

How can I fill in my form?

**UPD**: Here is relevant [bug report](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=104597)  with 8 duplicates, first of which opened in 2014.

Comment: It now has 13 duplicates... but still needs public pressure to get the development team's attention. Some work has been done on this last year, but the ball was dropped somehow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is a bug in LibreOffice. I found a workaround. Maybe it will useful for somebody.

- Open the original pdf in LibreOffice. The letters are reversed.
- Export the reversed file to pdf (`File`-> `Export as PDF…`) and save
  under different name. Now Document Viewer shows letters in reversed
  order, but LibreOffice shows the file correctly.
- Edit the reversed PDF in LibreOffice.
- Finally, export the reversed file to PDF format. Check with Document Viewer that file looks OK.

Comment: This was a complete definition of "modern problems require modern solutions"! However, it may fail during this process for some of the text boxes.